# How to get from ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType Type it is mede from attributes?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

How to get from `ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType` `Type` it is mede from attributes (`ProtoIncludeAttribute` for example)?

for example we had created an assembly from:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(TypeCode.MyClassChildCode, typeof(MyClassChild))]
public class MyClass {}

[ProtoContract]
public class MyClassChild: MyClass{}
```

We have got `ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType` for our `MyClassChild`. And we want to get `TypeCode.MyClassChildCode` from it. How to do such thing?

Comment: it seems as if `ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType` clears its `ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.Type` from `ProtoIncludeAttribute` attributes

Comment: Can you please clarify/re-phrase the question? I simply don't understand what you are trying to ask. I can almost certainly *answer* it, but I need to understand the question first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* sure that I understand the question, but it *sounds* like you are asking either:

- can I tell whether a `MetaType` was made from attributes, vs by hand
- or: can I get the actual attributes that were used

If that/those is/are the question(s), then: `MetaType` does not explicitly track this. The information from the attributes is used to configure the `MetaType`, and is then discarded. It is not uncommon, for example, to partially configure a type via attributes, and then apply some tweaks through code (for parts only known at runtime). All of the *configuration* is available on the `MetaType`, though. You mention `ProtoIncludeAttribute`, which is the sub-type data: once the `MetaType` has been constructed, this is available via `.GetSubtypes()`. Likewise there is `.GetFields()`, and a range of properties for type-level configuration options (`UseConstructor`, etc).

There are *some* pieces which might be tricky to query at the moment - surrogates and factories leap to mind.